# combine GNU parallel with nested for loops and multiple variables

Tags: bash, loops, parallel-processing, bioinformatics, fastq

I have n folders in destdir. Each folder contains two files: *R1.fastq and *R2.fastq. Using this script, it will do the job (bowtie2) one by one and output {name of the sub folder}.sam in the destdir.

```
#!/bin/bash

mm9_index="/Users/bowtie2-2.2.6/indexes/mm9/mm9"
destdir=/Users/Desktop/test/outdir/

for f in $destdir/*
do
fbase=$(basename "$f")
echo "Sample $fbase"
bowtie2 -p 4 -x $mm9_index -X 2000 \
-1 "$f"/*R1.fastq \
-2 "$f"/*R2.fastq \
-S $destdir/${fbase}.sam
done
```

I want to use gnu parallel tool to speed this up, can you help? Thanks.

Comment: highly similar to biostars "Question: Generating shell scripts"  https://www.biostars.org/p/162555/#162558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bash function:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_bowtie() {
  mm9_index="/Users/bowtie2-2.2.6/indexes/mm9/mm9"
  destdir=/Users/Desktop/test/outdir/
  f="$1"
  fbase=$(basename "$f")
  echo "Sample $fbase"
  bowtie2 -p 4 -x $mm9_index -X 2000 \
  -1 "$f"/*R1.fastq \
  -2 "$f"/*R2.fastq \
  -S $destdir/${fbase}.sam
}
export -f my_bowtie
parallel my_bowtie ::: $destdir/*
```

For more details: `man parallel` or http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, you can normally just put `echo` on the front of your commands and send the list of commands, that you would have executed sequentially, to `GNU Parallel`, to execute in parallel, like this:

```
for f in ...; do
   echo bowtie2 -p 4 ....
done | parallel
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I did it right but it still processes each subfolder at a time.

Comment: Have you got multiple CPUs/cores? Try adding `-j 8` right at the end after `parallel` to run 8 at a time.

Comment: Maybe try `for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo sleep 10; done | parallel` and see how long it takes to do 4 sleeps of 10 seconds each in parallel.

Comment: Yes! it worked. but i got this sort of error message : "sample cannot examine process 1 because you do not have appropriate privileges to examine it.  Try running with sudo." It still gives the correct output. Not sure why though.

Comment: Or remove `| parallel` temporarily and see what list of commands your script is sending to GNU Parallel.